# Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '3255+' to data type int.

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, runtime-error, boxing

```
    /****** Script for SelectTopNRows command from SSMS  ******/
SELECT *


FROM Zuege as a

INNER JOIN [ResultateProzessModellZug_PF3_PF3_SimFV_2015_mNT_mSKT_L91_mZuschlaege_SKT] as b

ON a.ZuglaufID = b.Zuglaufid

LEFT JOIN [SysPue].[dbo].[VISUM_I_Knoten_Netz2015] as c
   on [KnotenNummer] = Nr

LEFT JOIN [SysPue].[dbo].[LINIE_I_Richtung_Fahrplan2015] as d
    on d.ZugNr = LineRouteName

WHERE Zugvariante = 216
and ModellzugID in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
and Qualitaetszug = 1
and Inland = 1
```

It's givin be back this ERROR:

```
Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '3255+' to data type int.
```

I am really new to SQL i don't have an idea what might be wrong.  Thanks for your help.

Bob

Comment: One of these columns (KnotenNummer, Nr , ZugNr, LineRouteName) has "3255+" that not integer. You need to cast all sides as varchar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the datatypes of every column that is involved in a comparison.   Comparisons are found in the `ON` clauses of your JOINS, and in the `WHERE` clause.

Any time you are comparing a string (varchar) to a number (integer or other numeric type), you need to CAST the number-type column as a string (varchar).   Otherwise SQL Server will try to implicitly CAST the string as a number, and if it can't, it will raise the error you are seeing.

So, if for example you find that `Zugvariante` is a varchar, then you need to make `216` a string by putting it in single quotes like this:

```
WHERE Zugvariante = '216'
```

If `d.ZugNr` is a number and `LineRouteName` is a string, then you need to compare them both as strings:

```
CAST(d.ZugNr AS varchar(31)) = LineRouteName
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is with one of the JOINs being between an INT column and a NVARCHAR column, and the latter contains '3255+' that cannot be converter to an integer.

I suggest that you check the column types of:

```
a.ZuglaufID and b.Zuglaufid
[KnotenNummer] and Nr
d.ZugNr and LineRouteName
```

and make sure the types match.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the columns contained in the WHERE clause are not an integer field.
To solve the problem, search the string as a string.
Example:

```
SELECT *
FROM   Zuege as a
       INNER JOIN [ResultateProzessModellZug_PF3_PF3_SimFV_2015_mNT_mSKT_L91_mZuschlaege_SKT] AS b ON a.ZuglaufID    = b.Zuglaufid
       LEFT  JOIN [SysPue].[dbo].[VISUM_I_Knoten_Netz2015]                                    AS c ON [KnotenNummer] = Nr
       LEFT  JOIN [SysPue].[dbo].[LINIE_I_Richtung_Fahrplan2015]                              AS d ON d.ZugNr        = LineRouteName
WHERE Zugvariante   = 216 -- (IF [Zugvariante] IS VARCHAR)
  AND ModellzugID IN ('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10') -- (IF [ModellzugID] IS VARCHAR)
  AND Qualitaetszug = '1' -- (IF [Qualitaetszug] IS VARCHAR)
  AND Inland        = '1' -- (IF [Inland] IS VARCHAR)
```

Comment: Or you can convert it to INT

Answer (score -1):

The data contained in that column contains values that cannot be converted to an integer.

The Plus + value is causing the conversion to fail. Remove the + using some code to clean up the string. (Hint: Replace comes to mind.)